# How to retrieve a DHCP address for a VLAN?

Tags: systemd, dhcp, systemd-networkd, nftables, vlan

Context: my French ISP (Orange fibre) provides crappy routers and I replaced it with a Ubiquity ER-4 a few years back. I now would like to use a small PC running Debian 10 and `systemd-networkd`.

In order to retrieve the public IP of my router, I need to send a DHCP request tagged with a specific VLAN. Below is my setup - it's been hours I am trying to get the IP but the DHCP call does not complete (no answer). One of the problems may be the format of the option `90` that must be used as part of the DHCP call, but I would first like to make sure that the general approach to getting an IP for a VLAN is sound.

First I define the VLAN in a `.netdev` file:

```ini
[NetDev]
Name=orange.832
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=832
```

I then plug this VLAN into an interface in a `.network` file:

```ini
[Match]
Name=enp2s0
Type=ether

[Network]
Description=ethernet interface with VLAN attached
VLAN=orange.832

# In case of 'tagged only' setups, you probably don't need any IP
# configuration on the link without VLAN (or: default VLAN).
# For that just omit an [Address] section and disable all the
# autoconfiguration magic like this:
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
IPv6AcceptRA=no
IPv6SendRA=no
```

Finally, I configure the VLAN (also though a `.network` file) to retrieve an IP address via DHCP:

```ini
[Match]
# matches the VLAN on enp2s0
Name=orange.832

[Network]
Description=orange internet
DHCP=ipv4
#KeepConfiguration=dhcp
IPForward=yes

[DHCPv4]
#SendRelease=false
VendorClassIdentifier=sagem
UserClass=FSVDSL_livebox.Internet.softathome.Livebox3
UseHostname=no
# below is the authentication string which I have a hard time setting but it is completely specific to Orange in France
SendOption=90:string:\x00\x00\x00\....

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes
```

My firewall is for now completely open (`/etc/nftables.conf`):

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

 flush ruleset

 table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
    }
 }
```

Does this setup looks sound? (i.e. is this a correct way to set up `systemd-networkd` to retrieve an IP for a VLAN?)

One of the things which is a bit alarming is that I do not see any mention of the VLAN in the links:

```
root@router:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e2:69:59:33:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e2:69:59:33:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.201/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e2:69ff:fe59:33a3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e2:69:59:33:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e2:69:59:33:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: orange.832@enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e2:69:59:33:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

UPDATE following up on comments:

- `/etc/network/interfaces` does not exist, `/etc/network/interfaces.d` is empty and `vlan` is not installed because I use `systemd-networkd`
- `networkctl` output

```
root@router:~# networkctl list
IDX LINK       TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo         loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp2s0     ether    no-carrier  configuring
  3 enp3s0     ether    routable    configured
  4 enp4s0     ether    off         unmanaged
  5 enp5s0     ether    off         unmanaged
  6 orange.832 vlan     no-carrier  configuring
```

Below is also `networkctl status`

```
root@router:~# networkctl status -a | cat
● 1: lo
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: loopback
                         State: carrier (unmanaged)
                    HW Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
                           MTU: 65536
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
                       Address: 127.0.0.1
                                ::1

● 2: enp2s0
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/enp2s0-ETH0-wan.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: no-carrier (configuring)
                          Path: pci-0000:02:00.0
                        Driver: igc
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Controller I225-V
                    HW Address: 00:e2:69:59:33:a2
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9216)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: none
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 4/4
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: n/a
                          Port: tp

Aug 19 18:41:36 router systemd-networkd[249]: enp2s0: Link UP

● 3: enp3s0
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/enp3s0-ETH1-lan.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: routable (configured)
                          Path: pci-0000:03:00.0
                        Driver: igc
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Controller I225-V
                    HW Address: 00:e2:69:59:33:a3
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9216)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 4/4
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: 100Mbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: tp
                       Address: 192.168.10.201
                                fe80::2e2:69ff:fe59:33a3
                       Gateway: 192.168.10.1 (Ubiquiti Networks Inc.)
                           DNS: 192.168.10.3
             DHCP6 Client DUID: DUID-EN/Vendor:0000ab1193e3b0e6f387bfe80000
                  Connected To: n/a on port 98:fa:9b:78:f7:8b
                                ap-couloir on port f0:9f:c2:73:34:fe (eth0)

Aug 19 18:41:36 router systemd-networkd[249]: enp3s0: Link UP
Aug 19 18:41:38 router systemd-networkd[249]: enp3s0: Gained carrier
Aug 19 18:41:40 router systemd-networkd[249]: enp3s0: Gained IPv6LL

● 4: enp4s0
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: ether
                         State: off (unmanaged)
                          Path: pci-0000:04:00.0
                        Driver: igc
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Controller I225-V
                    HW Address: 00:e2:69:59:33:a4
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9216)
                         QDisc: noop
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 4/4
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: n/a
                          Port: tp

● 5: enp5s0
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: ether
                         State: off (unmanaged)
                          Path: pci-0000:05:00.0
                        Driver: igc
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Controller I225-V
                    HW Address: 00:e2:69:59:33:a5
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9216)
                         QDisc: noop
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 4/4
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: n/a
                          Port: tp

● 6: orange.832
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /etc/systemd/network/wan.network
                          Type: vlan
                         State: no-carrier (configuring)
                        Driver: 802.1Q VLAN Support
                    HW Address: 00:e2:69:59:33:a2
                           MTU: 1500 (max: 65535)
                         QDisc: noqueue
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
                       VLan Id: 832
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1
              Auto negotiation: yes
                         Speed: n/a
                          Port: tp

Aug 19 18:41:36 router systemd-networkd[249]: orange.832: netdev ready
Aug 19 18:41:36 router systemd-networkd[249]: orange.832: Link UP
```

Comment: What does `/etc/network/interfaces` look like? Is the package `vlan` installed?

Comment: Can you also add `networkctl list` output? That shows if the interfaces are handled by systemd-networkd.

Comment: @tink: I updated the post but please note I use `systemd-networkd`

Comment: @raspi: updated in the post, as well as `networkctl status`

Comment: The Intel Ethernet Connection I225-V is known to have some issues [see here](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/lqb4km/for_people_having_i225v_connection_issues/) or [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/intel-ethernet-controller-3-i225-v-problems.3765867/). Doesn't exactly sound similar to your problem, but the knowledge that the NIC chip may be flaky puts another wrinkle to the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working systemd-networkd setup which:

- Renames physical NIC to `phy0` for better management
- Has VLANs for WAN (internet) and LAN
- WAN uses DHCP
- MAC addresses are spoofed for LAN and WAN VLAN interfaces for better management and logging
- LAN has DHCP server enabled
- ISP doesn't use DHCP `SendOption`, just plain DHCPv4

### Physical NIC

`/etc/systemd/network/10-phy0.link`: (Renames physical NIC with certain MAC address to `phy0`)

```ini
[Match]
MACAddress=4d:ec:ef:04:76:8e

[Link]
# Rename NIC for better management purposes
Name=phy0
Description=Physical ethernet port 0 behind motherboard
# Use Jumbo frames
MTUBytes=9000
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
AutoNegotiation=yes

# Disable some HW accelerations because possible NIC bugs
ReceiveChecksumOffload=no
TransmitChecksumOffload=no
TCPSegmentationOffload=no
TCP6SegmentationOffload=no
GenericSegmentationOffload=no
GenericReceiveOffload=no
LargeReceiveOffload=no
```

`/etc/systemd/network/phy0.network`: (Attach VLANs to NIC)

```ini
[Match]
Name=phy0

[Network]
Description=Network for phy0
# Attach VLANs
VLAN=lan0
VLAN=wan0
DHCP=no
IPForward=yes
IPMasquerade=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
# It is "dumb" because of VLANs
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes


[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes
ARP=no
Multicast=no
AllMulticast=no
Unmanaged=no
Promiscuous=no
```

### VLANs:

#### LAN:

`/etc/systemd/network/lan0.netdev`:

```ini
[NetDev]
Description=LAN VLAN
Name=lan0
Kind=vlan
# Change MAC for better management and logs
MACAddress=ba:f4:4d:17:1b:48

[VLAN]
Id=123
LooseBinding=yes
ReorderHeader=yes
```

`/etc/systemd/network/lan0.network`:

```ini
[Match]
Name=lan0

[Network]
Description=LAN network
BindCarrier=phy0
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.100.1/24
Domains=home-net.lan
IPForward=yes
IPMasquerade=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=nearest-bridge
# See [DHCPServer]
DHCPServer=yes


[Link]
ActivationPolicy=always-up
ARP=yes
Multicast=no
AllMulticast=no
Unmanaged=no
RequiredForOnline=yes
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes

# Act as DHCP server
[DHCPServer]
BindToInterface=yes
ServerAddress=192.168.100.1/24
# Start from .128
PoolOffset=128
DefaultLeaseTimeSec=21600
MaxLeaseTimeSec=86400
EmitDNS=yes
DNS=192.168.100.1
EmitNTP=yes
NTP=192.168.100.1
EmitRouter=yes
EmitTimezone=yes
```

#### WAN (internet):

`/etc/systemd/network/wan0.netdev`:

```ini
[NetDev]
Description=WAN0 VLAN
Name=wan0
# Use standard MTU for internet
MTUBytes=1500
Kind=vlan
# Change MAC for better management and logs
MACAddress=0a:94:cf:7b:71:07

[VLAN]
Id=1000
LooseBinding=yes
ReorderHeader=yes
```

`/etc/systemd/network/wan0.network`

```ini
[Match]
Name=wan0

[Network]
Description=Internet
BindCarrier=phy0
DHCP=yes
DNS=192.168.100.1
IPForward=yes
IPMasquerade=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=no
LLMNR=no
LLDP=no
EmitLLDP=no
MulticastDNS=no


[Link]
ARP=yes
Multicast=no
AllMulticast=no
Unmanaged=no
RequiredForOnline=no
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
```

### nftables

On netdev address family allow only VLAN tagged and ARP traffic on `phy0`:

```
table netdev if_traffic {
  chain physical_in {
    type filter hook ingress device phy0 priority filter; policy drop;
    ether type vlan counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    meta protocol arp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
  }
}
```

**Note**: `netdev` rules will cause `nftables` to not start correctly in boot because interfaces might not exist yet (if you add for example allowed MAC/IP addresses rules for VLAN interfaces) so you need to enable `nftables` restarting with:

```bash
systemctl edit nftables
```

And add:

```ini
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
```

### Troubleshooting

systemd-networkd debug logs can be enabled with (requires reboot AFAIK):

```bash
systemctl edit systemd-networkd
```

And adding:

```ini
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Now you can see DHCP logs with for example:

```
journalctl -b -o short-monotonic --no-hostname -u systemd-networkd -u systemd-udevd
```

And should look like something like this:

```
[   10.747475] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: Requested configuring of the DHCPv4 client.
[   10.749483] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client is configured.
[   10.765793] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: link_check_ready(): DHCPv4, DHCPv6, DHCP-PD or IPv4LL is enabled but no dynamic address is assigned yet.
[   14.371914] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: STARTED on ifindex 4
[   14.372147] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease.
[   14.372362] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: link_check_ready(): DHCPv4, DHCPv6, DHCP-PD or IPv4LL is enabled but no dynamic address is assigned yet.
[   14.612883] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
[   14.648075] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: Received message from RAW socket, processing.
[   14.648446] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: OFFER
[   14.648669] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: REQUEST (requesting)
[   14.683557] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: Received message from RAW socket, processing.
[   14.683858] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: ACK
[   14.703211] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: lease expires in 3h 59min 59s
[   14.703397] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: T2 expires in 3h 30min
[   14.703557] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 client: T1 expires in 1h 59min 59s
[   14.704047] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCPv4 address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24, gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX acquired from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[   14.704224] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: Requesting DHCPv4 address (n/a): XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 (valid for 3h 59min 59s, preferred for 3h 59min 59s), flags: tentative, scope: global
[   14.704371] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: DHCP: No static routes received from DHCP server.
[   14.704506] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: Requesting DHCPv4 route (n/a): dst: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 1024, flags: n/a
[   14.704649] systemd-networkd[453]: wan0: Requesting DHCPv4 route (n/a): dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, prefsrc: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 1024, flags: n/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `ethtool` capabilities are enabled (on):

```
tcp-segmentation-offload generic-segmentation-offload generic-receive-offload rx-vlan-offload tx-vlan-offload hw-tc-offload

ethtool -K <physical_iface> xxx on
```

and try again.